# FTP help 12.04 Server

Tags: server, ftp

I am very new to Linux / Ubuntu so please excuse my ignorance.

I have installed ubuntu server 12.04.  I have installed vsftpd.  I have edited vsftpd.conf and made sure I have uncommented local_enable & write_enable are set to YES.  The vsftpd service is running.  Ports 20 & 21 have been allowed in ufw.  I am able to ping to my router and also ping to www.google.co.uk so as far as I am aware that means DNS is being resolved.

I can also log on via SSH with no problems at all (Not sure if that has any relevance but thought I'd mention it)

What I can't do is connect using 'filezilla' , 'cuteFTP' etc. This is the msg I get back from Filezilla

---

I have restarted service. When I log in as anonymous I connect but can't do anything. I have double and treble checked username and password. As I say I log into SSH with same credentials OK everytime.

```
Status:    Connecting to 192.168.0.2:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Command:    USER grant
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS *************
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

As I say I am very new at this so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The fact that filezilla says "Connection established" plus the success of your telnet test tell us that there's no problem with the basic connectivity and that the server is listening and not blocked by a firewall. So that pretty much only leaves authentication. Did you restart vsftpd after editing the conf file i.e. `sudo service vsftpd restart`? What happens if you try to open a connection from filezilla as 'anonymous' with an empty password?

Answer (score 0):

The  error message says
*Error: Could not connect to server*. Most probably a connection issue.

Are you able to reach the Linux Server from any other machine on the network apart from FTP Server ?

Go to another machine on network and execute the following command :

**telnet my.ftp.server.com 21**

If the above command shows a a FTP banner like  *220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)*  the connectivity between the FTP Server and client machine is working.

As a next step, you could check VSFTPd logs:

*cat /var/log/vsftpd.log*

Comment: Sorry for being total NOOB but how/where do I do the telnet command.  As for the log it has 6 entries all same apart from the timestamp saying 'Sun Aug 25 10:41:48 2013 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.0.3"

Comment: The result from the Telnet command is as follows - telnet GTPserver 21 Trying 127.0.1.1... Connected to GTPserver Escape character is '^]^' 220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5).  It then just sits there until I escaped out

Comment: If you want to provide additional information please do so by editing your question. Don't hide it in a comment.